# How to avoid superposition of character arrays?

Tags: c++, arrays, string, character

I created this simple class:

```
class stringa
{
public:
  char *Str;
  stringa(const char *Value);
};
```

My idea was that you would create an object to the class Stringa and use this object as something like a string.

I defined the constructor as the following:

```
stringa::stringa(const char *Value)
{
  Str = new char;
  int i = 0;
  for(i = 0; Value[i] != '\0';i++)
  {
    Str[i] = Value[i];
    Str[i+1] = '\0';

  }
  return;
}
```

Everything worked fine. I could call: stringa S1 = "HelloPutAnythingHere"; and it would work, the problem came when i created more than 1 object to this class.

i realized that if the first object, S1, had more than 12 characters, and i created another object S2, the ending characters of S1 wouldnt appear.

So if i had this:

```
stringa S1 = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789";
stringa S2 = "br";

cout << S1.Str << endl << S2.Str;
```

would only show: 
*abcdefghijkl*  and  *br*, as if the rest of S1 had been completely destroyed.

I supposed that S2 was being created in the middle of S1. Some code i added confirmed this.

The First character of S1 ('a') was being created at Address *0x8663008*, and the last one ('\0') was being created at Address *0x866302c*.  While the first character of s2 ('b') was being created at *0x8663018*, the position which should contain the letter 'q' from the S1.

So my question is the following: **How can i avoid the superposition of character arrays without a constant size? Is it impossible the way im approaching this?**

I know i could be using the string library, but that would go against the purpose of me writing this code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Str = new char;
```

allocates enough room for exactly one character. So `Str[0]` will be a valid reference that one one character, but `Str[i]` for any `i > 0` will be undefined behaviour (except that you can use the address of `Str[1]` as long as you don't attempt to dereference it).

Undefined behaviour is what it says: undefined. It may happen that for certain values of `i`, the storage represented by `Str[i]` is not being used by any other object, so your program appears to work ok for those values of `i`. Or it may happen that using `Str[3]` causes your computer to burst into flames. (Note: the former is more likely than the latter, but *there are no guarantees*.)

You can allocate enough space for `len` characters using `Str = new char[len];`, but obviously you need to know the value of `len`. And, as you note, you could use a variety of library functions to simplify this process.

Answer (score 3):

You allocated a single char for`Str` : you must allocate an array of characters.
Your program has undefined behavior.

std::string does not require a constant size as it internally manage th buffer, and reallocate on demand, which is basically what you'd need to implement.